# Multiple DB Connections in Eloquent with slim

Tags: php, eloquent, slim

I try to add more DB connections to my Eloquent in my Slim framework application.

And I do this:

```
$app = new \Slim\App([
    'db' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'localhost',
        'database'  => 'products',
        'username'  => 'user',
        'password'  => 'pass',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ],
    'db_second' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'localhost',
        'database'  => 'second',
        'username'  => 'user',
        'password'  => 'pass',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ],
]);

$container = $app->getContainer();

// connect to db with Illuminate larvel
$capsule = new \Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager;
$capsule->addConnection($container['settings']['db']);
$capsule->setAsGlobal();
$capsule->bootEloquent();
/// END connect to db

// to accsess the $capsule with our container from our controllers
$container['db'] = function($container) use ($capsule){
    return $capsule;
};
```

Now I don't know how to add another connection the `db_second` configuration that I have in the settings.

And how should I use this connection in the model?

Answer (score 3):

i found the Answer if someone need:

```
// connect to db with Illuminate larvel
$capsule = new \Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager;
$capsule->addConnection($container['settings']['db']);
$capsule->addConnection($container['settings']['db_second'], '**db_second**');
$capsule->setAsGlobal();
$capsule->bootEloquent();
/// END connect to db
```

and in the Model file  i put:

```
protected $connection = '**db_second**';
```

i put in ** at the name to use in the addConnection and in the Model
need to be the same name.